# How to do proper Error Handling using Web Workers?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, web-worker

I'm using Web Workers in my application to handle heavier calculations. Therefore I need to catch errors in the worker threads and pass them to the main thread so I can handle them there accordingly. It's important to me that I can add custom information to that error dynamically at runtime because I need it in the main thread.

So something like this I thought (this is not the application code but rather a very bare bone example to get the message across):

```html
<!-- index.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Web Worker Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
// main.js

const worker = new Worker('./js/web-workers/fibonacci.js');

worker.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
  console.log('MessageEvent:', e);
});

worker.addEventListener('error', (e) => {
  // Here I want to access the 'customProperty' set in 'fibonacci.js' somehow
  console.log('ErrorEvent:', e);
});

worker.postMessage(42);
```

```js
// fibonacci.js

self.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
  try {
    const result = fibonacci(e.data);
    self.postMessage(result);
  } catch (err) {
    const error = new Error(err.message);
    error.customProperty = 'This is what I want to access in main.js';
    throw error;
  }
});

const fibonacci = (num) => {
  let a = 1, b = 0, temp;

  while (num >= 0) {
    temp = a;
    a = a + b;
    b = temp;
    num--;
  }

  return b;
};
```

The problem is that the `ErrorEvent` object in the `error` event listener (`main.js`) doesn't hold a reference to that `customProperty` I set in `fibonacci.js`. What is a good way to do that?

Comment: Will it always be a string? Is there a downside to just adding it to the message/

Comment: @TKoL In the application it will always be an integer (a specific id). I'm not sure if there is a downside. Do you mean that instead of throwing an error I should set the `customProperty` to an object and send it back via `postMessage`?

Comment: I mean, if in `app.js`, at `worker.addEventListener('error', (e) =>` you have access to the error string you set in your worker, then you can just throw an error in your worker that has a string message that you want. I don't know exactly what you're doing, but lets say in your worker, when you Error under certain conditions, you want to throw an error and send some custom data like a count. You could do `throw new Error('count={"count":4}')` in your worker, and then in app.js you could check if `count={` appears in your error string, and if it does, parse it like JSON and do something with it

Comment: Or you could use `postMessage` and set an `error` property on the object you post, and then in your receiver function check if the error property is set

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of both of your suggestions as well but I was not sure if there is a "better" way :) Maybe I go with the first idea to encode the property in the error message string. The reason is so that I can use the `error` event listener in `main.js` which seems a little bit cleaner to me if something goes wrong in the worker.