# Service worker - handling errors on the front end

Tags: javascript, service-worker, service-worker-events

I am looking to handle the error from a service worker in the front end.
I saw this question - [How to do proper Error Handling using Web Workers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59357504/how-to-do-proper-error-handling-using-web-workers)

I tried the onerror - I tried using a post message from the service worker and listen for it on the front end. I tried listening for a on error. I couldn't find a way to get the message in the front end script again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the end I found the broadcast channel API. This worked great for sending messages back and fourth

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API